# What is the meaning here list in array calling

Tags: arrays, chef-infra, chef-recipe

Below I have environment file and recipe can you explain I am not getting what is the list here.

```
{
  "json_class": "Chef::Environment",
  "description": "prod environment",
  "default_attributes": {
   },
  "chef_type": "environment",
  "override_attributes": {



       "user": {
            "mapr": {
            "id":               "application",
            "group":            "application",                
        },
        "local" : {
            "id":               "chef",
            "group":            "chef"

        },
        "ldap" : {
            "id":               "ldap",
            "sudo":             true,
        },

}

  "name": "prod"
}
```

Below is the recipe  what is the list here i did not get

```
node['user_create'].each do |list, user|
group user['group'] do
    group_name user['group']
    gid        user['gid']
    action [:create]
    ignore_failure true
end
user user do
    username  user['id']
    uid       user['uid']
    group     user['gid']
    home      user['home']
    manage_home true
end

 if list !='ldap'
```

How list is passing here in if condition

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually passing in any attributes via the environment, which you can see because the values of `default_attributes` and `override_attributes` are both just empty hashes `{ }`. The data you've included there is just ignored by Chef as noise. In the future I recommend you use the Ruby DSL for environment files as it has more error checking for things like this (though not perfect error checking).

As an aside, you've been asking a lot of questions on here and seem to be struggling with Chef. Please consider joining the [Chef community Slack team](https://community-slack.chef.io/) and asking there instead as it's a full chat system and thus the community could offer real-time help rather than here random blurbs.

Comment: Sorry i have missed the }

Comment: I am very new to devops till now i have worked as system admin suddenly from last 2 months i am in chef but did not get much help me how can I